# Setting commandLink value through ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandlink

I have been using primefaces in JSF and  trying  to set commandLink value through managedbean class.

```
<p:commandLink value="#{loginBean.userClass}" id="userclass" action="{user.userClassAction}" />
```

**ManagedBean:**

```
 public String getUserClass()
 {
        return "userClass";
 }
```

I am asking that, is this correct way to that process from server side

Any suggestion for this .. Is this format correct , if so how can i use it appropriate way.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to achieve? The value is the text of the link. It would be "userClass" in this case and I'm not sure this makes sense here.

If you want to change the css class you may do that via the `styleClass` attribute.

If you really want to have some kind of dynamic text for the link. Then yes, using a managed bean is probably the only (non-hacky) way to do so.

If you only want to care about internationalization, then you better use the standard java-way for that. Using .properties files, referencing them via `#{msg['key']}` and declaring them for JSF via:

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>your.pkg.MessageBundle</base-name>
    <var>msg</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern. i need to set`commandLink text` dynamically ..Which one is better either by `Properties` format or via 'Managed Bean' format.

Comment: This depends on how dynamic it should be. In most cases it would probably change only for different languages, then go with the `Properties`. If you need to change it for some other reason, then it is not possible via properties and you need to do it with the help of your ManagedBean.